# Is there any time limit for python console as my continuous loop stops after some hours?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I created a continuous loop which continues to be repeated after every 30 seconds as I used `time.sleep()` function but problem is this that this script stops automatically after approximately 2 hours.

The thing which I understand is that there is some kind of function in python which stops the kernel if script is not finished after as my script don't have any kind of floss from which it should be said that this program ends and the result is returned.

Here is the loop which I use in my script

```
def continuous(interval=30,arg=""):
    import time
    a="True"
    if arg=="":
        arg="my url"
    while a=="True":
        my_funtion(Url=arg)
        time.sleep(int(interval))
```

Comment: What does `my_funtion` do? Can it raise an error? Can it run out of memory?

Comment: actually my function is my site scraper, it does not return any error and memory i dont know about but it doesn't raise memory error

Comment: My guess is that something happens in `my_funtion`. A scraper could run into recursion problems or memory problems, or an unhandled timeout issue. Python won't stop your infinite loop on its own.

Comment: is there any thing you know which i can do to solve memory problems, during running it consumes 171.8 MB of memory

Comment: as you say it runs out of memory, is it due to output or large data frame which is being stored in script after every run

Comment: You could store the dataframe on disk via `pandas.DataFrame.to_csv`. But your disk also does not have infinite memory, so your loop cannot run forever.

Comment: No, there is not time limit.

Comment: Python itself imposes no limit, but if you are using a platform like a computing cluster there might be a limit imposed by that.

Comment: i run my program through python launcher and recieve output from the program in form of xlsx and the size of that xlsx file hardly reaches 7 kb some time so i dont think that python will stop due to memory out because i have 4 gb ram with almost 70 percent usage while running program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@timgeb thanks for the help.
I figured that this error was due to memory as listed due to output which i was receiving from the program which was appended and No item was appended in list every time the program was run when i removed that from my program, my program is working from that time till now